# how to prevent UICollectionview's cellForItemAtIndexPath from calling if all the items are displayed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

All the items are being duplicated when I scroll. I use GCCategoryCell as reusable cell identifier.

```
CollectionCell *cell=[collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GCCategoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I have only 5 items in array I return by using numberOfItemsInSection. When I apply scrolling, images are duplicated.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(__unused UICollectionView *)collectionViewIn cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SmsContent *objSms=[arrContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *strImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/smsgupshup/%@/%@";, 
    objSms.strSmsId, objSms.strImageName]; 
    [cell.photoView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImagePath]]]]; 
    [cell.photoView setTag:indexPath.row]; 
    [cell.btnPhoto setTag:indexPath.row]; 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @RohitKP `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to be exact ;)

Comment: @RohitKP  SmsContent *objSms=[arrContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    
    NSString *strImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/smsgupshup/%@/%@", objSms.strSmsId, objSms.strImageName];
    
    [cell.photoView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImagePath]]]];

    
    [cell.photoView setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btnPhoto setTag:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

Comment: I've added your code in your question. How are your items duplicated ? if you have only 5 items in your array, `numberOfItemsInSection:` should return 5 and you couldn't have more than 5 cells. Add some log in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, log the `indexPath` you got in parameter and the `strImagePath` you create.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your `numberOfItemsInSection` code?  How many cells do you have on screen at once?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo thanks for advising to NSLog. I was actually reloading UITableview and UICollectionview at the same time which was causing the issue.